# how to run a shell script as root user?

Tags: ruby, shell, capistrano, expect, sudo

I have a script which I need to invoke as root user from capistrano,
so how can I do it with sudo option?

I'm using capistrano run method as follows:

```
set :use_sudo, true
set :user, 'some user'
set :runner, "root"
set :password, 'somepass'
role :list, "

desc "expect"
task :panky, :roles => :list  do
        run "#{sudo} wrapper.exp"
end
```

Comment: post your entire cap script in gist..

Comment: This is the sample script which i'm trying to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `sudo` instead of `run`

```
sudo "wrapper.exp"
```